# How do I play a game i installed by disk?

Tags: wine, games

I installed Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare with Wine and it installed correctly but I do not know how to launch it. It comes up with an error that I do not have the disk inserted but I do. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1

Answer (score 1):

You have to download [NoCD patch](http://m0001.gamecopyworld.com/games/pc_call_of_duty_4.shtml) and apply it. The game should work. Also consider [making a report](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=12804) about your experience.